# Using Pandas to plot Frequency of X against Y, where X is a 0 or 1 [Python,CSV,Pandas]

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a CSV file which has been generated and altered to the current form;

[Quick snapshot of sample Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8QfH8.png)

I want to be able to plot a graph that will have the X along the X axis as normal, and the Y axis to be a frequency 'True' values i.e (1's) So that I can visualise the relationship between time and frequency of the event occurring.

Thus far I have attempted a melt and using value_counts but they seem to give absolute not relative to the X value. I understand the data will likely need sorting additionally before plotting but I'm not sure the best way to go about this.

Many thanks for any help.

Comment: It's always a good idea to give an example of your expected output, in your case a sketch of the graph you want to plot. Because maybe it's just me, but I am not entirely sure what you mean by frequency of true values on the y axis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either plot a histogram which probably would work. or you can do a groupby 'x' to find aggregate of the sum of 'y' with code s shown below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data = np.array([[1988,1988,1988,1989,1990,1990,1991,1991], [0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0]])
df = pd.DataFrame(data.T, columns = ['x', 'y'])
df=df.groupby(['x']).sum()
print(df)
```